# Как в nodejs prisma делать условия "больше/меньше" при выборке?

Tags: node.js, prisma

Подскажите как в prisma делать выборки больше/меньше?

```
select * from prisma where `on`=true and status='WAITING_REGISTRATION' and time > '2022-12-04 00:00:00.0000000'
```

как добавить условие time > '2022-12-04 00:00:00.0000000'

```
await prisma.profile.findMany({where: {on: true, status: 'WAITING_REGISTRATION'}});
```

Вопрос может звучать глупо - но я правда ни как не могу найти пример как это сделать!?

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#gt

Comment: А вот как эта называется - спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ну как подсказали в коментариях
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#gt

```
let profiles = await prisma.profile.findMany({where:
        {
            on: true,
            status: 'WAITING_REGISTRATION',
            time: {
                gt: '2022-12-04 00:00:00.0000000',
            }
        }
}
);
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)